# 802.11n router supporting 802.11n as WAN connection?

Tags: networking, wlan, 802.1

I have an existing 802.11n WLAN router with an Ethernet connection as its upstream WAN connection (router A).  I would like to get another 802.11n WLAN router (router B) and have it use router A as its upstream WAN connection. Router B needs to connect to router A via 802.11n with WPA2 security.

Is this possible? Any WLAN routers support this notion of connecting to anothe WLAN router as its upstream WAN connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just put the WLAN in client mode and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I also want users to be able to connect wirelessly to router B with WPA security. So essentially router B would be creating a 2nd wireless network. Are there such WLAN routers that can be both in client and server mode?  Which ones?

Comment: Just what are you really doing here?

Comment: Basically I have a site 300' in width. The DSL modem and main WLAN router is on one side. I want wifi access across the whole site.  They are no power outlets for about 150' in the middle. So I'm trying to have a WLAN towards the middle of the site to provide full coverage. I thought having a WLAN router in the middle would be a possible solution.  The middle router would connect to the original for its WLAN and devices could also connect to it for wifi.